# Is the union of members of a countable family of measurable sets excluding finitely many of them measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

To make my question clear: "let {$E_k$} $^\infty_{k=1}$  be a countable family of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, is $\bigcup\limits_{k\geq n}^{}$$E_k$ measurable? (n a finite integer)"

I know countable union of measurable sets is still measurable, but would that be true even taking out finitely many of them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's still a countable union.

Comment: That's where I get confused. I try to explain by using definition of "countable" which is there exists a 1-1 corresponding map to rationals. But how if finitely many elements are taken out from the pre-image?

Comment: @Unavailable Because $\emptyset$ is measurable, we can always think of finite unions as infinite unions by adding the empty set.

Comment: @Hermès Really interesting point of view. But if we adding finitely many empty sets, isn't that we just count once since they are exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is called "countable" if there exists a 1-1 map to naturals.

By taking $$f(n) = n-k$$ as bijection it's obvious that $$\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots\}$$ is countable.

Comment: Ha, I made a huge mistake in definition of countable. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes the set $B=\bigcup_{k \geqslant n}^{\infty}E_k$ is meassurable.

We have that $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$ is measurable from the definition of a sigma algebra

Now $B=E$ \ $(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup...\cup E_{n-1})$

Again $(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup...\cup E_{n-1})$ is a measurable set as a finite union of measurable sets.

Thus $B$ is a measurable set as a set theoritical difference of measurable sets.

Note that a finite collection of sets is also a countable collection.